# Qt inherit QSpinBox and QPushButton

Tags: qt5, qpushbutton, qspinbox

I would like create my CustomQSpinBox .

This CustomQSpinBox must inherit of QPushButton and QSpinBox
but when I compile this code :

```
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QPushButton>

class CustomQSpinBox : public QSpinBox, public QPushButton
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  CustomQSpinBox (QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~CustomQSpinBox ();
  void initMinMax(int min, int max);
  void init();

signals:
  void needNumpad();

public slots:
  void clicked();

};
```

I get an error :

> erreur : C2594: 'static_cast'ÿ: conversions ambigu‰s de 'QObject *' en
>   'CustomQSpinBox *'

How I must do my inheritance ?

Comment: why exactly do you inherit from two classes ( both originating from QObject giving you your error... "diamond problem" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance )? You should only need to derive from QSpinBox itself ( or to be precise, one CustomSpinBox class inherited from QSpinBox and one CustomPushButton from QPushButton if required)

Comment: I need to know when the user click on the QSpinBox. The QSpinBox has ButtonSymbols = noButton

Comment: then you can completely rely on the standard QObjects and use the signal/slot system of qt ( set a valueChanged() signal to a slot of your desire ) See signals http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html here and signal/slot explained here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: The QSpinBox is in readonly, and when I click on, it open a numPad. So I can't use valueChanged.

Comment: and your numPad does setValue() on your (readOnly) QSpinBox? `setValue() will emit valueChanged() if the new value is different from the old one.` ( warning: if you say no, then I will most likely ask why you use that spinbox in the first place )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the numPad is closed, the value is set in the QSpinBox. The problem is so to open the numPad when I click on the QSpinBox.

For the moment I manage with this code :

```
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMoveEvent>
#include <QResizeEvent>

class CustomQSpinBox: public QSpinBox
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  CustomQSpinBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~CustomQSpinBox();

  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
  void moveEvent(QMoveEvent * event);

signals:
  void needNumpad();

public slots:
  void clicked();

private:
  QPushButton * button;

};
```